# Bad scrolling behavior specially due to dispatchOnMessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, knockout.js, scroll

I'm experiencing a very bad scrolling behavior in my site, & when trying to investigate using Chrome's dev tools & recorded what is happening, I found a very bad performance hit in calling this function `dispatchOnMessage` (which is called multiple times while scrolling) from chrome's `extensions::messaging` file, which I don't know how it could be related to my code in the first place!
[image]

& here is the function itself:
[image]

I've just upgraded to knockout 3.3.0, & even when downgrading back to the previous 3.1.0, problem still exists.

I've noticed a performance hit due to using the [enscroll jquery plugin](http://enscrollplugin.com/) (although it is smaller than the `dispatchOnMessage` function), but even after completely disabling it, problem still exists.

I'm investigating on Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit), & even when trying firefox 40.0.3, the problem still exists.

Is there anyway to investigate more on how this is happening?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Found anything? Having the same problem.

Comment: Well, I found nothing related to this issue, but concerning my case, I found that I was loading a lot of user-related images in a static part of the page (chatting component static to the viewport), & although they were hidden but they were loaded in the page, when I postponed showing them until after user clicks on their wrapper, it enhanced the performance a lot

Comment: After a lot of profiling, it turns out that in my case the problem was the presense of a lot of buttons on the screen. Changed them to spans, and the performance problem went away. Strange.

Comment: Check this link for your buttons' case https://benfrain.com/we-need-a-better-button-its-too-slow-and-wont-behave/ :)

Comment: Thanks. Great article.